# AngularJS creating a service with dot syntax API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to create an API service that my controllers can use instead of directly interfacing with the `$http` service.

I have:

```
app.factory("API", function($http) {

    var service = {
      performRequest: function(path, method, params, success) {
        $http({
          url: path,
          method: method,
          params: params,
          withCredentials: true
        }).success(function(data) {
          success(data);
        });
      }
    }

    return service;
  }
);
```

And the way it's used is:

```
API.performRequest("/signout", "POST", null, function(data) {
   // on success
});
```

What I'd like is to be able to have a `.success` property like the `$http` service, because currently `function(data)` doesn't imply what it's for.

What I want is:

```
API.performRequest("/signout", "POST", null).success(function(data) {
   // on success
});
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Return  `$http` promise from `performRequest`

```
app.factory("API", function($http) {
    var service = {
      performRequest: function(path, method, params, callback) {
       return  $http({
          url: path,
          method: method,
          params: params,
          withCredentials: true
        });
      }
    }
    return service;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks this works. What I'm really wondering though is in general how I would do something like that. Say I wasn't using $http and I wanted a `.success` property on my service. How would I do that in a generic situation?

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly but can use promises created by `$q` library and use `then`